# SQL Server: add column for rows since value changed

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains 3 columns: personID, weeknumber, and event.   Event is 0 if there was no event for that person in that week and 1 if there was.

I need to create a new column weekssincelastevent which will be 0 for the week where event=1 and then 1,2,3,4 etc for the weeks afterwards. If there is a later event then it starts from 0 again. E.g.

| personID | weeknumber | event | weekssincelastevent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | NULL |
| 1 | 3 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 6 | 0 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | NULL |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 0 | 1 |

The column should be NULL before the first events and all values NULL where a personID never has event.

I can't think how to write this in SQL.

The table has ~600m rows (60m personIDs with 100 weeknumbers each, although some personIDs don't have all the weeknumbers).

Many thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a gaps and island problem here. The first part, in the CTE, puts the data into "groups". Each time there is an event that's a new group. it also calculates the number of weeks that past since the prior week (which is set to `0` for rows hosting an event). Then in the outer query we `SUM` the number of weeks past in each group, giving the number of weeks that have passed:

```sql
WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT PersonID,
           WeekNumber,
           Event,
           COUNT(CASE Event WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY WeekNumber ASC
                                                     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS Events,
           CASE Event WHEN 0 THEN WeekNumber - LAG(WeekNumber) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID ORDER BY WeekNumber ASC) ELSE 0 END AS WeeksPassed
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT PersonID,
       WeekNumber,
       Event,
       CASE WHEN Events = 0 THEN NULL
            ELSE SUM(WeeksPassed) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID, Events ORDER BY WeekNumber ASC
                                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
       END AS WeekSinceLastEvent
FROM Groups;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=64089c465d9870af831fb284f599ddd5)

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a conditional aggregate within a windowed function:

```
SELECT  t.PersonID,
        t.WeekNumber,
        t.Event,
        WeeksSinceLastEvent = t.WeekNumber - MAX(CASE WHEN t.Event = 1 THEN t.WeekNumber END) 
                                             OVER(PARTITION BY t.PersonID ORDER BY t.WeekNumber)
FROM    dbo.T AS t;
```

The key parts are:

1. `CASE WHEN t.Event = 1 THEN t.WeekNumber END` Only consider week number where it is a valid event. Since `MAX` with ignore nulls this will only consider relevant rows
2. `OVER (PARTITION BY t.PersonID ORDER BY t.WeekNumber)` - Only consider rows for the current person, where the weeknumber is lower than the current row.

**[Example on DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=eeef916980ed14f18a698252060991c0)**

Comment: Far more succinct that mine. 